How to remove mudblazor keyboard navigation on radio button
How to remove mudblazor keyboard navigation on radio button.
(https://mudblazor.com/components/radio#keyboard-navigation)
I tried to replace the @onkeydown event without success, it seems to be overwritten by the keyboard navigation event.
I'm expecting to remove the effect of all the keys on the value of the radiobutton.
thx

I used @onkeydown:stopPropagation on the MudRadio tag.
Their was MudNumericField inside the MudRadio wich was still triggering the keydown event, so I also added @onkeydown:stopPropagation on the MudStack inside MudRadio
<MudRadioGroup>
    <MudStack>
        <MudRadio @onkeydown:stopPropagation>
            <MudStack @onkeydown:stopPropagation Row>
                <MudElement HtmlTag="span">text 1</MudElement>
                <MudNumericField />
                <MudElement HtmlTag="span">text 2</MudElement>
                <MudNumericField/>
                <MudElement HtmlTag="span">text 3</MudElement>
            </MudStack>
        </MudRadio>/>
    </MudStack>
</MudRadioGroup>


You could try use js interop e.preventdefault to disable keyboard events.
@page "/"
<MudForm>
    <MudRadioGroup  @bind-Value="SelectedOption" id="myRadio">
        <MudRadio Value="@("Radio 1")" Color="Color.Primary">Primary</MudRadio>
        <MudRadio Value="@("Radio 2")" Color="Color.Secondary">Secondary</MudRadio>
    </MudRadioGroup>
</MudForm>
<script>
    window.disableKeyboardInput = (elementId) => {
        document.getElementById(elementId).addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault();  // Disables all keypresses
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });

    };
</script>
@code {
    public string SelectedOption { get; set; }
    [Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("disableKeyboardInput", "myRadio");
        }
    }
}


@David Glad to hear that. Could you help to follow the instructions https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)
